# c++ listview tooltip implementation - not getting notification

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, atl, wtl

In my dialog WM_INITDIALOG handler I set the `LVS_EX_INFOTIP  | LVS_EX_LABELTIP` styles to the window like so:

```
ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(GetDlgItem(IDC_MAIN_LIST), LVS_EX_INFOTIP  | LVS_EX_LABELTIP);
```

The dialog's message map definition contains the following:

```
BEGIN_MSG_MAP(MyDlg)
    NOTIFY_HANDLER(IDC_MAIN_LIST, LVN_GETINFOTIP, OnMainListViewGetInfoTip)
    ....
    REFLECT_NOTIFICATIONS()
END_MSG_MAP()
```

where `OnMainListViewGetInfoTip` is:

```
LRESULT OnMainListViewGetInfoTip(int idCtrl, LPNMHDR pnmh, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    CString tempStr = L"tooltip message";
   LPNMLVGETINFOTIP pGetInfoTip = (LPNMLVGETINFOTIP)pnmh;
   if (pGetInfoTip != NULL)
   {
       pGetInfoTip->pszText = tempStr.GetBuffer();
   }
    return S_OK;
}
```

I don't get the LVN_GETINFOTIP notification at all. Also, I don't know if the conversion from pnmh to pGetInfoTip is correct and MSG_LVN_GETINFOTIP isn't identified by VS.

Comment: The code is about right, the problem is perhaps somewhere else...

Comment: In case it's relevant, [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774835(v=vs.85).aspx) that `LVN_GETINFOTIP` is only sent for subitem zero of a large icon view list control.

Comment: My view is ICON and 'Owner data fixed = true', other words I'm owner drawing it.

Comment: would owner drawing prevent receiving the notification?

Comment: Shouldn't you copy the tooltip message to the buffer rather that setting a reference:
wcsncpy(pGetInfoTip->pszText, tempStr.GetBuffer(), pGetInfoTip->cchTextMax);